# Meteor: Development only code?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'd like to run certain portions of my Meteor app only in development, and vice-versa.

How can I make code run only if in development? Is there a boolean/method available?

Comment: you can go there and check the different approaches. @Elegant.Scripting

Comment: I prefer the `jamgold:isdevelopment` package.